# Not able to add tag on resource AWS::ECS::Service

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I have below definition for ECS service:

```
        "EcsService": {
            "Type": "AWS::ECS::Service",
            "Properties": {
                "Cluster": { "Ref": "EcsCluster" },
                "TaskDefinition": { "Ref": "EcsTaskDefinition" },
                "DesiredCount": 1
            }
        }
```

---

for which CloudFormation service gives below message in Events tab:

### [image]

FYI..
I have defined tags for only two resources:

Tag for ecs container instance  `"Tags": [ { "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, "-instance" ] ]} }]`

This is another tag for elb security group `"Tags": [ { "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, "-elb-sg" ] ] } } ]`

---

1)
What is the meaning of this error? For EcsService

2) 
How to resolve it?

Comment: is it an error or warning

Comment: do you have any tags defined in your template

Comment: @ArunmainthanKamalanathan no I did not define any tag for ECS service

Comment: @ArunmainthanKamalanathan I defined tag for ec2 instance resource and elb security group

Comment: do you have any tags at all in the template. because i am guessing there might be another resource with tags on which ECS resource might be depending on.

Comment: It could be one of those tags causing the error/warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, in order do tagging in ECS, you need to opt in with new ECS ARN format as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-using-tags.html). It's still under opt-in period till end of this year [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-using-tags.html).

Kindly note that above is just warning, it will not stop or fail the cloudformation.

Comment: Yes.. I made these changes